# PHP mysql: 2 similar queries echoes results of 2nd query only

Tags: php, mysql

The result of the 2nd query overwrites the result of the 1st query. 
I've never run into a similar issue before.

**mysql table:**

```
updateid    picture  movie  
  14          1       1  
  22          0       1  
  33          1       0
```

**php file:**

```
<div id="imagecheck">
<?php 
$image_check= query("SELECT picture FROM list WHERE updateid = '$updateid' ");
foreach ($row as $image_check);

if (!($image_check))
{
?>

    <div class="result" id="camera<?php echo $updateid ?>">FOO</div>

<?php
}
else 
{
    ?>
    <div class="result" id="camera<?php echo $updateid ?>">BAR</div>

    <?php
}

?>
</div>
<div id="moviecheck">

  <?php 
  $movie_check = query("SELECT movie FROM list WHERE updateid = '$updateid' "); 
  foreach ($row as $movie_check);
    if  (!($movie_check))
    { 
    ?>
 <div class="result1" id="movie<?php echo $updateid ?>">FOO</div>

<?php
}
else 
{
    ?>
    <div class="result1" id="movie<?php echo $updateid ?>">BAR</div>

    <?php
}

?>
```

when i run those 2 queries, the result for

14 echoes BAR BAR

22 echoes FOO FOO

33 echoes FOO FOO

Any ideas what might go wrong here ?

Comment: try while mysqli fetch arrays then put the output into table . A sample can be found in w3schools . So atleast you know how to extract rows. Because what you are doing is more to screwing up the html structure use a simpler one first before using foreach

Answer (score 4):

Probably typos. you're using variable variables:

```
  foreach ($row as $$movie_check);
                   ^^--- note the doubled $
```

e.g.

```
$x = 'foo';
$foo = 'bar';
echo $$x; // outputs 'bar'
echo $x; // outputs 'foo'
```

As a general rule, never EVER use variable variables. They make for utterly unmaintainable and nearly impossible-to-debug code.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. As you said it was a typo when i copy pasted my code to SO, just fixed it.

Comment: The code's also very confusing. you use $row in the foreach, but never show how it's defined. no idea what this `query()` call is doing either. but as written now, your foreach() is overwriting the query() results as soon as the foreach starts.

Comment: If i remove the foreach, then the queries dont seem to work at all: they output bar for each item ( whereas not all rows in my table are 1. Some are 0 ).

Comment: well, where is `$row` being defined? unless it's being modified somehow by the `query()` call, all you're doing is doing a loop on the **SAME** data in both places.